# sftp not to rewrite existing file

Tags: bash, sftp

i have created a bash file to run sftp transfer between two server. All working fine now but i just want to ask how do i transfer a not existing file only? Right now when the server run the bash file, it will rewrite all existing file. Below is my sftp command.

```
#!/bin/bash

sftp serverB@IPAddress:/home/Server_B_User/IN/ <<EOF
put /home/Server_A_User/Desktop/OUT/*

exit
EOF
```

Comment: Perhaps `rsync` with SSH transport would be a better fit for your requirement?

Comment: @steeldriver, thank for your reply. I will give it a try.

Comment: Maybe this is just a typo, but there's nothing to transfer with a not-existing file... Or do you mean only transfer new files that aren't in the destination? +1 to rsync